# Смещение элементов пропорционально их длине (код внутри)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два элемента с разной длинной, при перетаскивании верхнего нижний должен перемешаться с такой скоростью, чтобы к моменту окончания верхнего, нижний тоже доехал до своего края, понимаю что расстояние `posdd` пройденное нижнем пропорционально зависит от разницы длины между верхнем `pos * (widthChdd / widthCh),` попробовал вставить это в код, но что-то идет не так

```js
position = false;
var startx = 0;
var prev_x = 0; //предыдущее значение
var direction = true; // направление

function SCREENmove() {
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  //измеряю ширину элементов чтобы запретить им отлипать от границы родителя
  widthP = $('.parrent').width();
  widthCh = $('.child').width();
  widthChdd = $('.childd').width();
  pos = $('.child').offset().left;
  posdd = $('.child').offset().left;
}
$(window).resize(SCREENmove);
$(document).ready(SCREENmove);


$('.parrent').mousedown(function(event) {
  position = true;
  startx = event.clientX;
})
$(document).mouseup(function() {
  position = false;
})

document.onmousemove = mousemove;

function mousemove(event) {

  if (position) {
    mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
    }
    // проверяю, изменилось ли направление, и если да, старт с этого места
    if (direction != (prev_x > mouse_x)) {
      startx = mouse_x
    }
    direction = prev_x > mouse_x
    prev_x = mouse_x;

    // проверяю, не превышает ли отступ ширины родителя
    mx = mouse_x - startx;
    if ((pos + mx / 20) > 0) {
      pos = 0;
    } else if ((pos + mx / 20) < (widthP - widthCh + 8)) {
      pos = widthP - widthCh + 8
    } else {
      pos = pos + mx / 20
    }
//пробую пропорционально смещать нижний элемент относительно смещения верхнего
    if ((posdd + mx / 20) > 0) {
      posdd = 0;
    } else if ((posdd + mx / 50) < (widthP - widthChdd + 8)) {
      posdd = widthP - widthChdd + 8
    } else {
      posdd = pos * (widthChdd / widthCh) //попробовал пропорционально сместить нижний относительно верхнего
    }

    $('.child').css('transform', 'translateX(' + pos + 'px)');
    $('.childd').css('transform', 'translateX(' + posdd + 'px)');
  }
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background: #8BC34A;
  margin: 2px;
}
.childd .block {
  background: #D81B60;
}
.parrent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
cursor: move;
}
.child,
.childd {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*transform: translateX(-394px);*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item-1 block" style="width: 100px">1</div>
    <div class="item-2 block" style="width: 120px">2</div>
    <div class="item-3 block" style="width: 300px">3</div>
    <div class="item-4 block" style="width: 70px">4</div>
    <div class="item-5 block" style="width: 150px">6</div>
    <div class="item-6 block" style="width: 200px">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="childd">
    <div class="item-1 block" style="width: 200px">1</div>
    <div class="item-2 block" style="width: 120px">2</div>
    <div class="item-3 block" style="width: 300px">3</div>
    <div class="item-4 block" style="width: 70px">4</div>
    <div class="item-5 block" style="width: 350px">6</div>
    <div class="item-6 block" style="width: 200px">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуй не по пикселям двигать их, а по процентам. Попробую набросать сейчас код

Comment: Думаю единицы измерения не важны если составить правильную пропорцию, пиксели и свойство translateX использовал чтобы не нагружать браузер.

Comment: Я сам не пойму почему не та пропорция. Сейчас попробую разобраться

Comment: Прости, больше часа сидел, так и не понял почему. Посмотри ещё сам, если нечего, то перепиши код функции